# How to extend functions onto imported types in Golang

Tags: go

I have an imported type

```
type ExternalType struct {
   quantity int
}


type ExternalArray []*ExternalType
```

I want to be able to implement the sort interface for ExternalArray for so that I sort it by quantity.

However, I am not sure how I could do that?

A concrete example is this:

https://play.golang.org/p/bEPtJ8NHQK

Comment: Maybe "How to implement an interface in Go" or "How to implement the sort interface in Go" would be a more descriptive title?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define a type in the current package that sorts a slice with the same element type as the imported type:

```
type byQuantity []*pkg.ExternalType

func (a byQuantity) Len() int           { return len(a) }
func (a byQuantity) Swap(i, j int)      { a[i], a[j] = a[j], a[i] }
func (a byQuantity) Less(i, j int) bool { return a[i].Quantity < a[j].Quantity }
```

[Convert](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions) the imported slice type value to the type defined above and sort:

```
a := pkg.ExternalArray{{1}, {3}, {2}}
sort.Sort(byQuantity(a))
// a is now sorted by quantity
```

Because the original slice and the converted slice share the same backing array, sort on the converted slice also sorts the original slice.

[playground example](http://play.golang.org/p/34Le_ERxdR)

Comment: Nice solution for multiple sort criteria on a single type!

Answer (score 7):

The [`sort.Interface`](https://golang.org/pkg/sort/#Interface) defines three methods which must be implemented:

```
// Len is the number of elements in the collection.
Len() int

// Less reports whether the element with
// index i should sort before the element with index j.
Less(i, j int) bool

// Swap swaps the elements with indexes i and j.
Swap(i, j int)
```

In this context this would look something like:

```
type ExternalType struct {
   quantity int
}

type ExternalArray []*ExternalType

func (ea ExternalArray) Len() int {
    return len(ea)
}

func (ea ExternalArray) Less(i, j int) bool {
    return ea[i].quantity < ea[j].quantity
}

func (ea ExternalArray) Swap(i, j int) {
    ea[i], ea[j] = ea[j], ea[i]
}
```

In order to do the sort you can then use [`sort.Sort`](https://golang.org/pkg/sort/#Sort), for example:

```
arr := ExternalArray{
    &ExternalType{quantity: 33},
    &ExternalType{quantity: 44},
    &ExternalType{quantity: 22},
    &ExternalType{quantity: 11},
}

sort.Sort(arr)
// `arr` is now sorted :-)
```

[Here](https://play.golang.org/p/BKuffu3XEW) is a working example in the playground.